# get scripting list from json using jq

Tags: shell-script, jq

> Update(start): answer the following line and you have answered the
> full question:
>
> Why does the following:
>
> ```
> echo '{"ipv4":["192.168.64.193"]}'|jq .ipv4[0]
> ```
>
> Give this error:
>
> ```
> no matches found: .ipv4[0]
> ```
>
> Update(end)

I m trying to create a list variable, containing the values from "ipv4" from this json:

```
{
    "list": [
        {
            "ipv4": [
                "192.168.64.193"
            ],
            "name": "node2",
            "release": "20.04 LTS",
            "state": "Running"
        },
        {
            "ipv4": [
                "192.168.64.192"
            ],
            "name": "node1",
            "release": "20.04 LTS",
            "state": "Running"
        }
    ]
}
```

HOSTS is a list of the ip addresses:

UPDATE: Thanks to @Kusalananda I am using this in the script `HOSTS+=$(echo $i|jq '.ipv4[0]')`

```
get_hosts(){
  unset HOSTS
  # unset NAMES
  jq -c '.list[]' file.json | while read i; do
      HOSTS+=$(echo $i | jq .ipv4)
      # NAMES+=$(echo $i | jq .name)
  done
  echo $HOSTS
  # echo $HOSTS
}
```

I get:

```
[
  "192.168.64.193"
][
  "192.168.64.192"
]
```

But I need:

```
  "192.168.64.193"
  "192.168.64.192"
```

So I tried:

```
...
HOSTS+=$(echo $i | jq .ipv4[0])
...
```

But then I get:

```
get_hosts:3: no matches found: .ipv4[0]
get_hosts:3: no matches found: .ipv4[0]
```

Note: this is one of the lines in the loop:

```
{"ipv4":["192.168.64.193"],"name":"node2","release":"20.04 LTS","state":"Running"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unquoted string `.ipv4[]` is a shell globbing pattern.  This pattern does not match any existing files and the shell you are using is configured to generate an error (like `zsh` does by default) rather than to retain the pattern unexpanded (like `bash` does by default).

Quote the expression used with `jq`:

```bash
echo '{"ipv4":["192.168.64.193"]}' | jq '.ipv4[0]'
```

---

To extract all IP addresses from the data that you provide in the question, get all elements of all `ipv4` arrays of the `list` array:

```bash
$ jq -r '.list[].ipv4[]' file
192.168.64.193
192.168.64.192
```

It's unlikely that you need to put these values into an array.  Instead, read them one by one and do whatever you need to do to them:

```bash
jq -r '.list[].ipv4[]' file |
while IFS= read -r ipaddr; do
    # use "$ipaddr" here
done
```

To read the names and the first IP address for each name:

```bash
jq -r '.list[] | [ .name, .ipv4[0] ] | @tsv' file |
while IFS=$'\t' read -r name ipaddr; do
    # use "$name" and "$ipaddr" here
done
```

The `@tsv` operator produces tab-delimited output of an array, and we use it here to pair up the name with the corresponding IP address for each entry in the `list` array.

Comment: Thanks, very good answer - the thing is that I actually need both "ipv4" and"name" to two arrays :-|

Comment: I ended up doing: HOSTS+=$(echo $i | jq '.ipv4[0]') and same for NAMES. Thanks again!

Comment: @ChrisG. You _really_ don't need to do that. See update.

Comment: Ok, interesting "@tsv" and IFS.  Not aware of these, thanks - much better

Comment: @ChrisG. `IFS` is the character that the shell will split the input on when reading with `read`.  The last loop in my answer uses this to split the input on tabs, into the two variables `name` and `ipaddr`. Run the `jq` command by itself to see what the loop gets as input.

Comment: Good stuff, I like it a lot - much cleaner and faster I presume